# Inno Setup With 4 Image JPG

Tags: inno-setup

I loaded 4 images .jpg (with botva2.dll) to use like background on my installer, however, the images just stay in welcome page (ID wpWelcome) one upon another.
How can i set each image like background in your respective page?

This is my idea:

image 1.jpg like bagkground on Welcomepage (wpWelcome)

image 2.jpg like background on Readypage (wpReady)

image 3.jpg like background on Installpage (wpInstalling)

image 4.jpg like background on Finishedpage (wpFinished)

Comment: please, show how you load the images.

Comment: I agree with jachguate. Maybe you should use `CurPageChanged`? But it would help alot if we could see the `[Code]`

Comment: At first, Botva is quite suspicious library and I wouldn't advice anyone to use it.

Comment: Ok TLama, so how can i use a diferent image .bmp on the example below:    image 1.bmp like bagkground on Welcomepage (wpWelcome)
image 2.bmp like background on Readypage (wpReady)        
image 3.bmp like background on Installpage (wpInstalling)
image 4.bmp like background on Finishedpage (wpFinished)